# In a function, is it possible to `return( eval ( expr ) )`

Tags: r

I am trying to do something like a global assignment within a function (e.g. with `... <<- ...`), using the following code

```
test_function = function(){
 return(eval(parse(text = "test <- 4^2"))) 
}
test_function()
```

Which doesn't assign `16` to `test` in the environment `test_function` is called.

However

```
test_function = function(){
  return(expression(test <- 4^2)) 
}

eval(test_function())
```

does!

Is there anyway of doing the former without resorting to the latter?

Comment: i think you just need to put more brackets into the parse statement. try surrounding the 4^2 inside a bracket and then try again.

Comment: that doesn't work for me...

Comment: try parse(text="4^2")

Answer (score 3):

Well, I would be careful. if you did just

```
test_function = function(){
 test <- 4^2
}
```

that value would not be in the global environment either, and that's essentially what you're doing in your first function. Note that

```
test_function = function(){
 return(eval(parse(text = "test <- 4^2"))) 
}
print(test_function())
# [1] 16
```

returns 16 so the assignment is happening in the function scope just as expected and being returned. There's no reason to think that would be have any differently. If you want to evaluate in the parent scope, then be explicit about it

```
test_function = function(){
 return(eval(parse(text = "test <- 4^2"), parent.frame())) 
}
test_function()
```

or if you want to always operate in the global environment, specify that

```
test_function = function(){
 return(eval(parse(text = "test <- 4^2"), globalenv()) 
}
test_function()
```

But really this seems like a poor design decision. It's not polite for functions to have global side effects like that. Make sure this is absolutely necessary for your application and you have no other options.

Comment: I don't want to do a global assignment, but to assign it in the environment of another function where it will be called.

Comment: So you want something that could do: `x=1 ; foo()` and then `x` might suddenly not be equal to 1 any more, and a variable called `z` might have appeared? Can you see why magically making variables appear and change in a calling function might be a bad idea?

Answer (score 2):

`eval.parent` may be a "safer" approach, if you want to assign into the calling framing of test_function.

```
test_function = function(){
    eval.parent(quote(test <- 4^2))
}
test_function()
test
# [1] 16
```

Comment: thanks, this works as well, presumably `eval.parent` is the same as `eval(..., parent.frame())` as in @MrFlick's answer...

Comment: it is the equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `assign()` with the assignment to the parent frame

```
> test_function <- function(){
      assign("test", 4^2, parent.frame()) 
  }
> test_function()
> test
[1] 16
```

Comment: thanks, but the question is, can you enclose the `assign` bit in a `return()`. The reason why I wish to do this is to avoid the impoliteness of declaring variables outside of the function scope except in the `return()` bit.

Comment: Ok, that wasn't explicitly mentioned in the question.  Do you want the function to return a number, or invisibly?